# Clang vs. LLVMC -- what's the difference?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

What's the difference between `llvmc.exe` and `clang.exe`? Which one do I use for compiling C or C++ code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

llvmc was an experimental driver that was intended to support multiple different source languages. Clang and Clang++ have always been the preferred way to drive the (C / C++ / Objective-C) compiler.  In fact, llvmc has been removed from mainline.

In short, you should definitely use "clang" and never "llvmc".

Answer (score 12):

`llvmc` is a frontend for various programs in the LLVM toolchain, in particular the `llvm-*` ones, ie by default it will try to use `llvm-gcc` and `llvm-g++` to compile C and C++ files.

You can pass `-clang` to `llvmc` if that's what you want to use, and it's probably possible to configure `llvmc` so `clang` will be used by default, but I have no idea how to do that.

I'd recommend to just use `clang` and `clang++` directly, which can be used as drop-in replacements for `gcc` and `g++`.

Answer (score 3):

LLVM originally stands for Low-Level Virtual Machine, and is today mostly used either:

- as a backend optimizer/compiler
- as a JIT compiler

On the other hand, Clang is a collection of libraries for dealing with the C language family that notably contains a compiler (`clang`) which acts as a front-end for C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ on top of the LLVM libraries.

So, in your case, you will want to use `clang` and `clang++` to compile C and C++ respectively, and don't worry about the fact that LLVM is used behind the scenes to optimize your code and deal with generation of machine instructions adapted to your architecture.

Comment: I think Mehrdad is asking specifically about [llvmc](http://llvm.org/cmds/llvmc.html) command. Which is  not the same as LLVM itself.

Comment: @Banthar: I noticed, and yes you can invoke Clang with the llvmc command, however that's a work around. llvmc is best used for llvm relative stuff (like executing optimizations passes etc...), it's really unneeded to use it in place of clang and just adds some overhead (both in execution time and in the developers' mind).